# How to use Mockito to verify stream callback

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, mockito

I developing an application an flutter and use clean architecture.

I created a use case return a List from a stream. The stream sends the List from an observer. Above is the code:

```dart
abstract class GetAllServicesObserver implements Observer {
  void onGetAllSuccess(List<Service> services);

  void onGetAllError(Exception error);
}

class GetAllServices extends UseCase<GetAllServicesObserver, NoParams> {
  final User _user;
  final ServiceRepository _serviceRepository;

  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  GetAllServices({
    @required User user,
    @required ServiceRepository serviceRepository,
  })  : _user = user,
        _serviceRepository = serviceRepository;

  @override
  action(observer, params) async {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    final _stream = _serviceRepository.all(_user);

    _subscription = _stream.listen((services) {
      observer.onGetAllSuccess(services);
    }, onError: (e) {
      observer.onGetAllError(e);
    });
  }
}
```

And I created an unit test to this use case:

```dart
test('should to return all services', () {
    //setup
    when(repository.all(user)).thenAnswer((_) async* {
      yield List<Service>();
    });
    final useCase = GetAllServices(user: user, serviceRepository: repository);
    useCase.observer = observer;

    //run
    useCase();

    //verify
    verify(observer.onGetAllSuccess(List<Service>()));
  });
}
```

But it's returns the follow message and not pass:

ERROR: No matching calls (actually, no calls at all).
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)

Would anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried untilCalled before verify? e.g.:

```
await untilCalled(some method that will be called)
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot run a `verify` unless you have a matching `expect`; for instance:

```
test('test description', () async {
    // Logic here
    expect(await mockClass.methodCall(), null);

    verify(mockClass.methodCall()).called(1);
});
```

Comment: It is false. expect and verify are two separate methods, and does not to be used together.